# is there a better way to implement a redis "rpushnx" function?

Tags: redis

I wanna implement a "rpushnx" function that:

1. if the key exists, do nothing. else
2. rpush strings to the list.
3. it is a multi-thread environment.

Currently, the code snippets are just like this:

```
    if (!redis.exists(db, key)) {
        synchronized (MyClass.class) {
            if (!redis.exists(db, key)) redisClient.rpush(db, key, list);    
        }
    }
```

But I think it is a little bit trivial.

Is there some nicer way to have it done ?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a better way. Your solution may work if you have a single multi-threaded application server, but it will not work in a distributed system with several application servers. Plus, it requires 3 roundtrips when the key does not exist.

You will be better served by leveraging a Lua script. Redis always executes Lua scripts atomically.

For instance:

```
eval "if redis.call( 'EXISTS', KEYS[1] ) == 0 then redis.call( 'RPUSH', KEYS[1], unpack(ARGV) ) end" 1 mykey val1 val2 val3 val4
```

Comment: Eventually  I use "zset" rather than "list", which solves my problem. Whats more, I am not familiar with Lua. . Thanks anyway @Didier.